# Sync contacts on android device with G+ information

Tags: contacts, sync

I have a contact on my phone that doesn't show anything but a phone number.  When I review that contact on my Gmail Contacts on the G+ section it shows their address, work address, phone, work phone, etc.

Is there a setting in Android or Gmail I need to adjust in order to get this to sync with my phone?

Answer (score 6):

On Gmail, make sure that contact is associated with the google+ profile. On the top right corner of the contact page, you should see **Connected Profiles** and below it a Google+ link.

I the account isn't linked and it doesn't suggest it. **Add** the person's Google+ Profile address as a **URL**

You can find the **Add** option on the left side of the contact page, right below the basic info.

Another option is to go to **Circles** under Gmail Contacts itself, locate the contact you want and merge it with the other Contact (in case they are not 1 already)

Finally, on Android, Install [Google+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus), if it isn't already installed, and on your Android Device under Google+ **Settings** make sure **Keep contacts up to date** is enabled. Then You may need to start merging contacts inside the **Android contacts**. (When I got mi phone, it did a poor job detecting and auto merging contacts)